# Rendering at small resolutions cause unexpected softness (lack of sharpness)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, blur

I'm very new to Blender, having just started yesterday, and my render is lacking the sharpness I'm expecting it to have.

I'm rendering a simple textured dodecahedron to a PNG of 192x192 pixels, with a transparent background.

**Depth of Field** is turned **off** (unchecked).

I'm rendering in **Perspective** lens with a **450 mm Focal Length**.
`(note: I've also tried rendering with a camera half as far and half the Focal Length, but got the same softness)`

I have "**Render Properties -> Sampling -> Render**" set to 16 samples.
`(this is identical even if I set to 128 or the default of 64 - identical render result)`

I've set the **Texture Interpolation** (texel sampling) to Linear, Closest, and Cubic, and it didn't make a substantial difference to my final result.

When I render at 512x512, it gives a nice crisp image like I am expecting. I can then open that image in Paint Shop Pro (an art program) and resize it with Paint Shop Pro to give a 192x192 image that is still nice and sharp. (Note: PaintShopPro has multiple resizing algorithms, but two different algos I tried both gave sharper results)

Yet, if I render it at 192x192 directly in Blender, the image is far far softer (less sharp) than I would expect.

I suspect I have some setting wrong somewhere, but don't know what to look for.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eevee fights aliasing by rendering multiple times with slight camera offsets. Those offsets are defined in pixels, not by percentage, so changing output resolution will change the offset:

[image]

Try setting it to $0.56$ px, as then it will reflect the change of your output resolution:

$${512\over192} = 2{2\over3}$$
$${1.5\over0.56} \approx 2{2\over3}$$

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the issue!